# Installing Qlik Sense on Windows 2012 r2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, qliksense

I'm trying to install Qlik Sense Desktop on Windows Server 2012 R2. The problem I believe is with the name entered as hostname during installation.

I tried using the hostname during installation process as the name of the server machine as well as the the ip address of the windows server but I get below error message whenever I try loading the Qlik sense hub app after installation

> This site can’t be reached

Answer (score 0):

If you're logged into the server, try https://localhost/qmc rather than the hostname. That should always work unless the services have failed to start up or something.

If you can get in there, then you can amend the accepted hostnames in the Virtual Proxy settings in the "Host Allow List" section.

If you can't get in there, it's possible it's trying to use the hostname you entered to connect between services - your best bet is to do a full uninstall and re-install - and probably keep the default hostname it proposes as this should always work and you can add additional hostnames at a later date.

Answer (score 0):

Are the services up and running ? Have you see if one of the ports used by QlikSense are available or were used by other application ?